# Spark Streaming job getting killed automatically after 3-4 hours, even after running in the background

Tags: spark-streaming

Running kafka-spark streaming integration to get data in real time. 
Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

#set auto.offset.reset = smallest

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafka")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3600)

brokers = *****
topic = ******

kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])

lines.pprint()

lines.saveAsTextFiles('/tmp/')

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Running job in background using this command:

/usr/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.2 --master yarn get_stream.py > stream.log 2>&1 &

This is the stream.log generated from the spark-stream job. This job is automatically getting shutdown after 3-4 hours. 
Error which I'm getting in the TRACE mode logging is (Not showing the whole log, it's too big):

```
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO StreamingContext: Invoking stop(stopGracefully=false) from shutdown hook
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG JobScheduler: Stopping JobScheduler
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO JobGenerator: Stopping JobGenerator immediately
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO RecurringTimer: Stopped timer for JobGenerator after time 1470906000000
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO JobGenerator: Stopped JobGenerator
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG JobScheduler: Stopping job executor
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG JobScheduler: Stopped job executor
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO JobScheduler: Stopped JobScheduler
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO StreamingContext: StreamingContext stopped successfully
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: DFSClient writeChunk allocating new packet seqno=29, src=/var/log/spark/apps/application_1470897979038_0002.inprogress, packetSize=65016, chunksPerPacket=126, bytesCurBlock=64512
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: DFSClient flush(): bytesCurBlock=64944 lastFlushOffset=64878 createNewBlock=false
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: Queued packet 29
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: Waiting for ack for: 29
    16/08/11 09:56:09 TRACE Tracer: setting current span null
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: DataStreamer block BP-730701491-10.102.224.120-1470897963878:blk_1073741871_1047 sending packet packet seqno: 29 offsetInBlock: 64512 lastPacketInBlock: false lastByteOffsetInBlock: 64944
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: DFSClient seqno: 29 reply: SUCCESS downstreamAckTimeNanos: 0 flag: 0
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.102.224.120:4040
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: DFSClient writeChunk allocating new packet seqno=30, src=/var/log/spark/apps/application_1470897979038_0002.inprogress, packetSize=65016, chunksPerPacket=126, bytesCurBlock=64512
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: Queued packet 30
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: Queued packet 31
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: Waiting for ack for: 31
    16/08/11 09:56:09 TRACE Tracer: setting current span null
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: DataStreamer block BP-730701491-10.102.224.120-1470897963878:blk_1073741871_1047 sending packet packet seqno: 30 offsetInBlock: 64512 lastPacketInBlock: false lastByteOffsetInBlock: 64944
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: DFSClient seqno: 30 reply: SUCCESS downstreamAckTimeNanos: 0 flag: 0
    16/08/11 09:56:09 TRACE Tracer: setting current span null
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: DataStreamer block BP-730701491-10.102.224.120-1470897963878:blk_1073741871_1047 sending packet packet seqno: 31 offsetInBlock: 64944 lastPacketInBlock: true lastByteOffsetInBlock: 64944
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: DFSClient seqno: 31 reply: SUCCESS downstreamAckTimeNanos: 0 flag: 0
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG DFSClient: Closing old block BP-730701491-10.102.224.120-1470897963878:blk_1073741871_1047
    16/08/11 09:56:09 TRACE ProtobufRpcEngine: 46: Call -> ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020: complete {src: "/var/log/spark/apps/application_1470897979038_0002.inprogress" clientName: "DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_258672080_15" last { poolId: "BP-730701491-10.102.224.120-1470897963878" blockId: 1073741871 generationStamp: 1047 numBytes: 64944 } fileId: 16590}
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: The ping interval is 60000 ms.
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: Connecting to ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (461299828) connection to ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020 from hadoop: starting, having connections 2
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (461299828) connection to ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020 from hadoop sending #10767
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (461299828) connection to ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020 from hadoop got value #10767
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: complete took 3ms
    16/08/11 09:56:09 TRACE ProtobufRpcEngine: 46: Response <- ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020: complete {result: true}
    16/08/11 09:56:09 TRACE ProtobufRpcEngine: 46: Call -> ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020: getFileInfo {src: "/var/log/spark/apps/application_1470897979038_0002"}
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (461299828) connection to ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020 from hadoop sending #10768
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (461299828) connection to ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020 from hadoop got value #10768
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: getFileInfo took 1ms
    16/08/11 09:56:09 TRACE ProtobufRpcEngine: 46: Response <- ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020: getFileInfo {}
    16/08/11 09:56:09 TRACE ProtobufRpcEngine: 46: Call -> ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020: rename {src: "/var/log/spark/apps/application_1470897979038_0002.inprogress" dst: "/var/log/spark/apps/application_1470897979038_0002"}
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (461299828) connection to ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020 from hadoop sending #10769
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (461299828) connection to ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020 from hadoop got value #10769
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: rename took 2ms
    16/08/11 09:56:09 TRACE ProtobufRpcEngine: 46: Response <- ip-10-102-224-120.ec2.internal/10.102.224.120:8020: rename {result: true}
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Interrupting monitor thread
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG AbstractService: Service: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl entered state STOPPED
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: stopping client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@7aa30390
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-fb5326d4-f089-4aff-b394-bc126f12a983/pyspark-f6c4c7f7-f6e5-4dcf-a9cd-cf03391413d9
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-fb5326d4-f089-4aff-b394-bc126f12a983
    16/08/11 09:56:09 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-fb5326d4-f089-4aff-b394-bc126f12a983/httpd-9104e927-bd6d-4338-bd20-fd01b7d3ce7f
    16/08/11 09:56:09 DEBUG Client: stopping client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@7aa30390
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running your program in yarn-client mode, i.e. the driver is on the submit host.

Looking at your log files, you will notice that the client gets a shutdown:

```
Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

most probably invoked by the enclosing shell, because your session was terminated. Sending the job to background doesn't prevent this, because the process is still tied to its parent, which is your session.

In addition to that, you use the console output to collect your results, which you shouldn't do, specifically because your already collect the same records in HDFS:

```
lines.saveAsTextFiles('/tmp/')
```

I would suggest the following to fix this:

a) run in cluster mode. add `--deploy-mode cluster` to your parameters 
b) If you still want to collect output, like you do, add `nohup` in front of spark-submit. `nohup` will detach your process from the parent process.